# Can't figure out how to use db:seed for rails in netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netbeans6.7, seeding

can't seem to get my seeds.rb file to run through the command "rake db:seed". I'm using netbeans and I'm a beginner to rails, so I could be doing something really simple and stupid =/. I know you're meant to put your seeds.rb file in the db directory but netbeans doesn't seem to have one or might have renamed it... any help out there?

Answer (score 0):

The rake task `db:seed` will load the Rails environment and then load and execute the file `db/seeds.rb`.

If you do not have a file `db/seeds.rb`, then make one (and if necessary make the `db` directory too).

Comment: yeah I've added in and everything and now when I try and run the "rake db:seed" command it complains about there being no such method... quite confusing... =/